# Constructing Useful SAT Instances

Tags: computational-complexity

Given a set of binary strings, all of length $s$, is it possible to construct a SAT instance with s literals that is satisfied only by those binary strings as assignments?

For example, consider the set $\{101, 110\}$. Can we construct a SAT instance with literals $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ such that it is satisfied only by the assignments $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 1$ or $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 1$, $x_3 = 0$?

It would be even more useful if this instance is an instance of k-SAT for some k.

Comment: I notice I seem to be getting downvotes. Apologies if this is not considered research-level, I am not especially familiar with this field and this pertains to a research problem I am working on.

Comment: Each $k$-CNF clause removes exactly one $k$-bit assignment. The example you give has six $3$-bit assignments that must be removed: $000, 001, 010, 011, 100,$ and $111$. For example, $(\neg x1 \lor \neg x2 \lor \neg x3)$ removes $111$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every such set of strings determines a collection of rows in the truth table, and so you want an expression that is logically equivalent to the disjunction of those rows. This gives a logical expression in disjunctive normal form, but every propositional assertion can be put into [conjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form), which makes it an instance of SAT.

Comment: Note that converting propositional assertions into conjunctive normal form, however, is quite computationally difficult: if we just want to preserve satisfiability, it's already $NP$-hard, and if we want to actually get an equivalent proposition in CNF then the only upper bound I know is $EXPTIME$ (although that's probably massive overkill).

Comment: Well, he wanted an expression that had exactly those satisfying instances, so one seems to need an expression that is exactly equivalent to the one I am talking about. But I agree that there is exponential cost in doing the conversion---and not only is there a cost for converting, but the resulting CNF expression can become exponentially longer than the original set.

Comment: I believe if additional variables are allowed there is polynomial 4-CNF encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose by "literals" you mean *variables*.

If you allow additional temporary variables
there is explicit polynomial encoding in 4-SAT
by carefully constructing the CNF.

First we construct CNFs for the satisfying assignments,
then do disjunction of the CNFs.

Encode binary string $s$ this way.
For the $i$-th digit introduce boolean variable $v_i$.
$1$ is $v_i$, $0$ is $\lnot v_i$.

A satisfying assignment is conjunction $ v_1' \land v_2'\ \cdots \land v_n'$
where $v_i'$ is either $v_i$ or $\lnot v_i$.

To encode the conjunction, use AND gate in CNF encoding.

The CNF for $ AND(A,B,C) := C \iff (A \land B$) is 
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \lnot A \lor \lnot B \lor C \\
& A \lor \lnot C \\
& B \lor \lnot C
\end{aligned}
$$

By using the AND gate and fresh variables $w_i$, encode each
satisfying assignment $s_i$ to a 3-CNF $C_i$.

Basically $C_i = \{AND(v_1',v_2',w_1), \ldots AND(v_k',w_{k-1},w_k), w_n \}$

Remains to encode the disjunction of the CNFs $C_i$.

Define the transformation $F(C_i)$ by introducing boolean
variable $y_i$ and add $\lor y_i$ to each clause of $C_i$
(this is just adding $y_i$ to the CNF clause).

If $y_i$ is $False$, then $F(C_i)$ is just $C_i$ and it
is satisfiable only by $s_i$.

To force at least one $y_i$ to be $False$ add the clause
$$ \lnot y_1 \lor \lnot y_2 \cdots \lor \lnot y_n$$.

So the final CNF is $CN = \{F(C_1) \ldots F(C_n), \lnot y_1 \lor \lnot y_2 \cdots \lor \lnot y_n\}$.

which by construction is 4-SAT and is polynomial in the size of
the input.

Using an AND gate adds 3 clauses and one new variable
and this is polynomial.

Comment: Why not just go directly to 3CNF? Make a Boolean circuit with two inputs per gate that implements the obvious DNF formula for the given set of truth assignments and then make extra variables for the internal states on each wire of the circuit and clauses for the consistency of each gate.

Comment: Well, it is not 4-CNF because of the last clause. Another approach for disjunction is just to OR the outputs of the CNFs in a single clause.